# 3rd order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been stuck on this ODE for a while and my attempts seem to lead nowhere. I'd be glad about any tips on which direction to go. The question: Find all real functions y such that
$$y'''(t)+e^{2t}y''(t)+\sin(t)y'(t)+\frac{y(t)}{t^2+1}=\cos{t}$$With boundary conditions $y(0)=1, y'(0)=0, y''(0)=-1$

My attempts: I've transformed it into a system of ODEs and checked whether the matrices commute (Magnus approach) which is not the case. Then I've tried to use Laplace, but the calculation of the transformed function for the 1st and 0th-order terms seems to be rather complicated so I gave up on that as well. I also don't think Fourier will lead to anything .

How to proceed?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is it a homework problem or coming from somewhere else?

Comment: I mean the fact that all the boundary conditions are at t=0 would suggest to me that perhaps there is a series solution to this problem. Those boundary conditions certainly define the maclaurin expansion .

Comment: @Yimin yes, it's a homework problem

Comment: This is very unlikely to have a closed-form solution.  You can get series solutions or numeric solutions.  Are you sure that is the actual question?

Comment: Thanks for your insight. The question is indeed asked this way. Since I'm not really interested in a numerical solution I tried via power series and via the Cauchy product formula found the first couple coefficients in the expansion of y (If I calculated correctly): $$y(t)=1-t^2+\frac{1}{3}t^3+\frac{1}{12}t^4+\frac{9}{120}t^5-\frac{25}{720}t^6+...$$Is this a known series? The professor said its a difficult homework problem and thus worth 10 points. So I was expecting a somewhat close form.

Comment: The coefficient of $t^2$ should be $-\frac{1}{2}$, so that $y''(0)=-1$. (I haven't checked the other coefficients.)

Comment: @Gonçalo you're right, thank you.